# Vue3 + Quasar SPA trying to authenticate with a Laravel API and getting a CSRF token mismatch (419 status code)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf, quasar

I have a application SPA Vue3 + Quasar and a backend Laravel API, on same domain (localhost), my SPA is on port 8080 and my API on port 80.

In SPA, every time my page refresh, I send a GET to /sanctum/csrf-cookie and them the CSRF Token is stored on browser application cookies.

Also, axios is sending correctly the CSRF token on requisition.

I tried to authenticate with my Laravel API (/login without the /api prefix), at dev environment an then I receive a 419 status code.

I don't know if is important, but my API is running with Sails, on a docker container.

Axios config on Quasar/Vue:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost/'
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Laravel .env

```
...
APP_URL=http://localhost
...
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8080
```

cors.php

```php
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Kernel.php,

```php
        'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
            SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Cookie Header of my request to /login:

```
Cookie:
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InJ0SXhRZDVEL21JaEUvL0ptTGdmUlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU28zenNEQ1VOYTR3NXRVd1JtcU1RaUsvK1BCTHpNUGtUZ3c3T3I0d3lKQjhlZzNjMkVIeDBoOFZWanJDVkw2cWc0RGRDM0NWako0cnN1RXdveThwZkE4dW51aS9Ia1FYVXVsSlpqdW9CK1F3amJTMlFITzhpSCtudDYvY2VpUnUiLCJtYWMiOiIyODkyMzhjYjU5YzMzODY2YTkxZTY3M2MzOWZkNDkwMGQyYjBjNDg0ZTgwMzM3ZDc5NjYwYTcyNWFmZTUyZjExIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlQxYXZ4WGhYZGZ5Lzk2WlF5QzJRUHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidE5QQUpaeFh3WWg4cjFJNG82SXNDY1FGUmplWFN5cG5na08zazRmbXFJRFhJVWdUZS81UzJ1RWNaaC84VWxxcTFPdWNuTXd5K0pDaW0zTDliME5BSHl2ZGw4M01lbk1EUDl6SnlVWWFLM2lxNHBTOFBmei9QQXhMaTZLazJSeEEiLCJtYWMiOiIwNjFlNTFkNzIzZTIyZDhjYTg0MmVhMGViMGZjYTU4MmZjY2VmOGMyOWRjODgyNGY3NmE3NjExZDIyYWVhMDU1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; 3mcV2b1Mp2zT3MoKAWWTOeGlp0TkNFu9FneRzMLK=eyJpdiI6InY1cUYwaXhjdnZlQVRiNDNqaFRMMEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaE52dVg0dnRYdmE2dDVUT0lUUkJWeXAyaXNkaXMvZkw3RjJwT0hrbkdybUx4K0JyZ2RZV2lMYjEvT3F2TUEvOWQzejkxN05SaHlZMVliUktmUnhVRkwwYTB4cDYzUVB5VFA3MnA5SmlhMmc1Y0VSY3NyMm1JVnd2Vk1XZmFlWU05dEZJWVQrSjFqQ2h6aktFemdFVWZ6cjJBM2MydHNIMlcxRSsvWk1xaDU0Y1RDcHBFUndOL2ZlMXBVWVhyUEQrNS8vOTI5Qmx0TmpMQUtZQ0sxUHZLMEd5MnpGdC91SnVDeDJ5RkF4Tkc0dUphNHhLRFQwUE5Vc0hlR29JaVZqQ3p4Yi9wTFpMUE42UmJOWXoxN0V2bGZlZHduTVRmZUdkcHVnLzBkOWQ0emQyajhjelptSG9XUzRDb3lmZVlpMk5OK1p0R2R2eTdET2FjcTVhVGR4WmRtNVd4ekQ4SHZaeEg3cTUxY0Y2ZVhFdWhJeDh1SUkreUkwdFBmMjErUmdGIiwibWFjIjoiYWVmY2NkY2NiZmJiY2ZhNjkyMTVhODE2MTg0MjkxNTYxZWQ0N2I4NzMyY2RjOWE2NDdiNGY4NjljYjk5NDY0YyIsInRhZyI6IiJ9
```

Edit:

I discover a new point:

Axios added a header named "Cookie" and inside put the XSRF-TOKEN..
I manually added a header named "X-XSRF-TOKEN" with my cookie which has stored early on Application's Cookies... And finally worked.
But I saw in many tutorials this proccess is automatically done by Axios... How can I achieve this?

```js
    const login = async () => {
      let cookies;
      await axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
        const { get } = useCookies(['XSRF-TOKEN']);
        cookies = get('XSRF-TOKEN');
      });

      axios.defaults.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = cookies;
      await axios.post("/login", form).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      });
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, please [edit] your question title to clearly explain the problem you're having or question you're asking. The majority of your current title is the useless repetition of the tags. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: What has all this to do with CORS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue after `Axios 1.6.0`. You have to modify your axios configuration and set `withXSRFToken` to true, as below:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
```

Take a look at https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/9152